# VS2012 professional Code Coverage

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, nunit, code-coverage

I´m searching for a way to generate code coverage reports on VS2012 professional and using Nunit. I know that VS2012 ultimate have a code coverage tool and with Nunit_Adapter you can generate the code coverage report, but the issue is that I am using VS2012 professional and does not have the option to generate the code coverage report.

Does someone knows a plug-in or a relative simple way to creates this reports on VS2012 professional?

Thanks,

P.S And if someone knows a way to creates this reports using Nunit framework on VS2010 it could be an option.

Answer (score 5):

Or if you want free (opensource) you can try [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) which is available as a [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCover/) package and use [ReportGenerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportGenerator/) to generate some nice reports.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a third party code coverage tool, such as [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) or [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/?gclid=CMKptcbK6bkCFcg1QgodwRUA8w).